# What is Crystal Report Service Pack version that matches crystal report runtime version 13.0.20.2399?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have developed a wep app using ASP.NET C#. In the development I used Visual Studio 2019. After hosting the application, I git this error anytime I try to generate report that I used Crystal report to design. I contacted the hosting site and they informed me that the version of Crystal Report runtime installed on their server is "13.0.20.2399". unfortunately, my runtime version is "13.0.4000.0".
This the error that I'm getting
"Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

I have downloaded Crystal Report Service Pack 20 but it did not work and even this version is not compactible with VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 13.0.19.2312 **CRVS201020_0-10010309.EXE** but the problem that it does not work with visual studio 2019 or 2022. You need install an older version of visual studio.